# Make browser show list of downloaded files?

Tags: javascript, browser, download

Users that download a file from a web site will sometimes have a problem locating the downloaded file. Each browser has its own way to show the download progress and the list of recently downloded files.

Is there a way to instruct the browser to display the list of recently downloaded files?

Comment: Not in any way that's consistent across browsers, if at all.

Comment: That's an answer as good as any. Perhaps you can upgrade it from comment to answer?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't a way to do this.